# How to use python classes in C++?

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I wrote a wrapper that allows me to use python functions in C++, the api looks like this:

```
auto module = python.getModule("pycode"); // calls PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault
CppPyFunction<int(int, int)> multiply(module, "multiply"); 
std::cout << "multiply(a, b): " << multiply(a, b); // calls PyTuple_New, PyTuple_SetItem, PyObject_CallObject
```

However, I dont really understand how to use python classes directly

I can use classes in a somewhat hacky way:

// python code

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name;
        print("Person: __init__" + str(name))

   def printName(self, string):
        print(self.name)

def makePerson(name):
    return Person(index);

def printName(person)
    person.printName()
```

Then the C++ code would be

```
auto personModule = python.getModule("Person");
CppPyFunction<PyObject * (std::string)> makePerson(module, "makePerson");
CppPyFunction<void(PyObject*)> printName(module, "printName");

auto alice = makePerson("Alice");
auto bob = makePerson("Bob");

printName(alice);
printName(bob);
```

But this is abit of a hack because it is not natural to create the functions def makePerson(name): and def printName(person).

Question1: Is there a way to call the Person constructor and methods directly from C++ without having to create a "factory method" in the python code?

Question2: Is there a way to construct a template "class" representation in C++ with nice syntax, eg

```
typedef ?? CppPyClass<???> ??? Person;
Person a("Alice");
Person b("Bob);
a.printName();
b.printName();
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of C++ framework or library for accessing Python? Which framework is it? What is `python`? What is `CppPyFunction`? Etc.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am writing my own framework because the C api is quite a pain to use. CppPyFunction<T()> is a template class where the operator() is overloaded. The operator() calls the python functions PyTuple_New, PyTuple_SetItem, PyObject_CallObject with the correct parameters, depending on the template input to CppPyFunction<T()> and returns the expected type. python is just a wrapper around Py_InitializeEx() and Py_Finalize()

Comment: Then excuse my curiosity, why are you writing your own framework? There are a few working C++ frameworks for Python already, like e.g. [Boost Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: I have not done this before, so I figured the python c api is the natural place to start. I will look into boost python too. At first glance boost python seemed to be about exposing C++ code to python, im not sure about the other way round

Comment: pretty sure you just need `PyObject_Call` or `PyObject_CallObject`, the class itself is callable